# Prevent Firebase $firebaseArray auto update

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I am working on a News Feed that is similar to Facebook News Feed. I am implementing it in the following sequence:

1. When app is started, get everything, but only push two item to show.
2. The user can scroll down to see more and I will add more to the list.
3. If there are any new items, the user needs to pull to refresh to add the new ones.

The only problem I have right now is that each time an item is added, `$firebaseArray` automatically adds the new item to my array that I do not want snyc changes (*I want to query once, get a set list*). I was wondering if anyone would know how to prevent the auto update?

Answer (score 1):

Look into .once this will allow you to get the data just once: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once

Comment: While `once()` would indeed help, the problem is that `$firebaseArray()` abstracts the `on()` away out of OPs code.

Comment: Right, which is why I don't think the OP can use it.

Comment: Thanks Frank and Mathew! I am using firebaseArray because I am doing this.        ```var queryOfeverything = firebase.database().ref("events").orderByChild("dateSince1970").startAt(nowSince1970);``` I am ordering the events that I am getting and I only want to get events past certain date. If I do use once, I can do a for each to include events that are past certain date and use orderby in angular. Is that the most efficient way to do it? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can do a .once after your query. As Frank said $firebaseArray just abstracts away some of the more complexities of firebase. Everything regular in their awesome api documentation will still work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding directly your `$firebaseArray` to the view, clone it to a scope (or controller) property that will be bound to the view. Factorize this process in a function you can call when the user pull-reloads so the the `$firebaseArray` is re-created.

A more appropriate approach would be to use Firebase's http api, with the angular `$http` service.

Edit: to clone the array to a scope var, try the following:

```
var allEvents = $firebaseArray(queryOfeverything);

allEvents.$loaded()
    .then(function(events){
        $scope.allEvents = angular.map(events, function(event) {
            return event; // you may want to replace this line - I am not very familiar with firebase.
        })
    });
```

Comment: I did something similar to this already if this is what you mean.  $scope.allEvents = $firebaseArray(queryOfeverything); $scope.eventToDisplay = $scope.allEvents. Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: This is because you are passing the `$firebaseArray`, which is technically a javascript object, by reference. You'd need to map (clone the array to a plain javascript array) to that $scope variable. I'll update the answer.